# Channel permissionOverwrites is working perfectly in 90% of the guilds but in some guilds its returning error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So as I said in the title in some guilds the channel `permissionOverwrites` is not working which leads to crashing the bot.

Here's the code:

```js
const qu = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
  (role) => role.name.toLowerCase() === '',
);
if (!qu) {
  try {
    let qu = await message.guild.roles.create({
      name: '',
      color: '#',
    });
    try {
      await message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel) => {
        await channel.permissionOverwrites
          .edit(qu, {
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
          })
          .then(console.log)
          .catch(console.error);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      await console.log(e);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    await console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Here's the error I get on the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'edit')
```

`channel.permissionOverwrites.edit`, `.create` and `.set` returns same error. I don't know what's behind this error, if you got any idea why please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every channel has `permissionOverwrites`. [`ThreadChannel`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ThreadChannel), and [`DirectoryChannel`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/DirectoryChannel) for example don't have them. If a guild has these channels cached, you will receive an error in your `forEach` loop. I'd log and check `channel.type` to see which types cause these errors.

To solve this, you either need to filter these out:

```js
await message.guild.channels.cache
  .filter(
    (channel) =>
      ![
        'GUILD_DIRECTORY',
        'GUILD_NEWS_THREAD',
        'GUILD_PRIVATE_THREAD',
        'GUILD_PUBLIC_THREAD',
      ].includes(channel.type),
  )
  .forEach(async (channel) => {
    await channel.permissionOverwrites
      .edit(qu, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
      })
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
  });
```

... or only include the ones you need (e.g. `TextChannel`, and `CategoryChannel`):

```js
await message.guild.channels.cache
  .filter((channel) =>
    [
      'GUILD_CATEGORY',
      'GUILD_TEXT',
      'GUILD_VOICE',
    ].includes(channel.type),
  )
  .forEach(async (channel) => {
    await channel.permissionOverwrites
      .edit(qu, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
      })
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
  });
```